# Как изменить частоту размещения маркеров на SVG Path?

Tags: html, css, svg, d3.js

Есть SVG Path. Он генерируется по данным пользователя и может принимать вид как кривой, как видно на скрине, так и простой линии.

Path генерируется в `d3` через `d3.line(...)`.

[image: svg path with mrkers]
Нужно реализовать возможность отображения маркеров на данной линии.
Проблема в том, что эти маркеры должны идти друг рядом с другом с некоторым отступом.
В данный момент, при моей реализации, их количество ограничено количеством опорных точек кривой.

Как это решить и сделать так, чтобы они отображались "плотно" друг к другу?
Может стоит использовать другой подход?

```html
<svg style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
    <defs>
        <marker id="marker-1" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="0" refY="10" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
            <line data-v-464173b1="" data-v-f620f4f0="" x1="0" x2="0" y1="10" y2="0" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px"></line>
        </marker>
    </defs>

    <path fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-linecap="round" marker-mid="url(#marker-1)" stroke-width="5px" stroke-dasharray=""
        d="M54.95397970441209,68.0743026828044L57.07970401893456,85.59202972259588C59.20542833345703,103.10975676238736,63.45687696250196,138.14521084197034,81.4214401648379,161.00276942403795C99.38600336717384,183.86032800610556,131.0636811428008,194.53999109065788,147.94743134236452,181.52897426519155C164.83118154192823,168.5179574397252,166.92100416542874,131.81626070424022,183.97830259519844,115.13579097794174C201.0356010249681,98.45532125164327,233.06037526100693,101.7960785345313,249.07276237902633,103.4664571759753L265.08514949704573,105.13683581741931"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот так можно все посчитать в runtime:

```
 // ищем необходимую точку
 var p1 = path.node().getPointAtLength(d);

 // ищем точку чуть дальше по пути
 var p2 = path.node().getPointAtLength(d + len/1000);

 // считаем угол в полярных координатах второй точки относительно первой 
 // и прибавляем к нему необходимый поворот
 var a = Math.atan2(p1.y - p2.y, p1.x - p2.x) + Math.PI/2;

 // считаем положение второй точки штриха за счет полученной только что нормали
 return `M${p1.x},${p1.y}L${p1.x+Math.cos(a)*size},${p1.y+Math.sin(a)*size}`
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
render();

function render() {
  let size = 20, offset = 5, distance = 10+d3.select('#distance').node().value /5;
  let svg = d3.select('svg');
  let path = svg.select('path');
  let len = path.node().getTotalLength();
  let count = Math.floor(len/distance);
  let data = Array(count).fill(0).map((d, i) => offset+len/count * i);

  svg.selectAll('path.marker').remove()

  svg.selectAll('path.marker')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .classed('marker', true)
    .attr('d', d => {
        var p1 = path.node().getPointAtLength(d)
        var p2 = path.node().getPointAtLength(d + len/1000)
        var a = Math.atan2(p1.y - p2.y, p1.x - p2.x) + Math.PI/2;
        return `M${p1.x},${p1.y}L${p1.x+Math.cos(a)*size},${p1.y+Math.sin(a)*size}`;
    })
}
```

```css
path {
  fill:none;
  stroke:red;
  stroke-width:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<input id="distance" type="range" value="50" onmousemove="render()"/><br>
<svg viewbox="0 50 500 500" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;">
    <path d="M54.95397970441209,68.0743026828044L57.07970401893456,85.59202972259588C59.20542833345703,103.10975676238736,63.45687696250196,138.14521084197034,81.4214401648379,161.00276942403795C99.38600336717384,183.86032800610556,131.0636811428008,194.53999109065788,147.94743134236452,181.52897426519155C164.83118154192823,168.5179574397252,166.92100416542874,131.81626070424022,183.97830259519844,115.13579097794174C201.0356010249681,98.45532125164327,233.06037526100693,101.7960785345313,249.07276237902633,103.4664571759753L265.08514949704573,105.13683581741931"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: `getPointAtLength`
а что, так можно было?)
чего-то я явно недосмторел в доках. спасибо за данный опыт

Comment: @ThunderAL =) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength

Answer (score 5):

### Способ с помощью векторного редактора

Идея состоит в том, что маркеры присоединяются к узловым точкам.
 **Поэтому, если добавить новые узловые точки, то появятся новые маркеры.**

В исходном примере было 5 узловых точек внутри линии и две точки на концах линии. Но на них не присоединялись маркеры, так как было указано на  маркеры в середине:

```
marker-mid="url(#marker-1)"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляем новые узловые точки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сохраняем файл в формате *.svg.

В принципе всё готово.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500" version="1.1"  style="height:500;width:500"> 
 <defs>
        <marker id="marker-1" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="0" refY="10" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
            <line data-v-464173b1="" data-v-f620f4f0="" x1="0" x2="0" y1="10" y2="0" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px"></line>
        </marker>
    </defs>
  
  <path  marker-mid="url(#marker-1)"  d="m55 68.1 2.1 17.5c1.2 9.8 3 25 7.6 40.5C68.2 138.4 73.5 150.9 81.4 161c7 8.9 16 15.9 25.5 20.4 14.9 7.1 30.8 8 41 0.1 8.6-6.6 13.4-19.4 18.2-32.5 4.7-12.7 9.5-25.7 17.9-33.9 8.4-8.2 20.6-11.6 32.6-12.6 12.3-1.1 24.4 0.2 32.5 1l16 1.6" id="path2" style="fill:none;stroke-width:5;stroke:#f00"/>
</svg>
```

Если нужно присоединить маркеры на концы линии, то добавляем:

```
marker-start="url(#marker-1)"  marker-end="url(#marker-1)"
```

Подробнее о маркерах [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=855).

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 500 500" version="1.1"  style="height:500;width:500"> 
 <defs>
        <marker id="marker-1" viewBox="0 0 20 20" refX="0" refY="10" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto">
            <line data-v-464173b1="" data-v-f620f4f0="" x1="0" x2="0" y1="10" y2="0" stroke="red" stroke-width="5px"></line>
        </marker>
    </defs>
  
  <path  marker-mid="url(#marker-1)"  marker-start="url(#marker-1)"  marker-end="url(#marker-1)" d="m55 68.1 2.1 17.5c1.2 9.8 3 25 7.6 40.5C68.2 138.4 73.5 150.9 81.4 161c7 8.9 16 15.9 25.5 20.4 14.9 7.1 30.8 8 41 0.1 8.6-6.6 13.4-19.4 18.2-32.5 4.7-12.7 9.5-25.7 17.9-33.9 8.4-8.2 20.6-11.6 32.6-12.6 12.3-1.1 24.4 0.2 32.5 1l16 1.6" id="path2" style="fill:none;stroke-width:5;stroke:#f00"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: да, тоже думал о том, что можно просто сделать больше опорных точек, думаю, так бы и поступил, если бы не обнаружил метод `getPointAtLength`

Answer (score 4):

Можно использовать такой приём: 
Вместо маркеров использовать атрибут `stroke-dasharray` с толщиной строки равной высоте маркера для одного патча.

*Расчет делается следующим образом:*

Длина Path в вашем примере равна `335px` Допустим нам нужно 10 верт. столбиков.
Их роль будет выполнять длина черты `3.5px` и пробел между ними будет `30px`  В сумме это `33.5px` - один из 10 сегментов линии.
Высоту столбика будет играть ширина `path` `stroke-width="20"`

```html
<svg style="height:500;width:500" viewBox="0 0 500 500"> 
  <defs>
    
  </defs>
  <path fill="none" stroke="red"   stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="3.5 30" d="M55 68.1L57.1 85.6C59.2 103.1 63.5 138.1 81.4 161 99.4 183.9 131.1 194.5 147.9 181.5 164.8 168.5 166.9 131.8 184 115.1 201 98.5 233.1 101.8 249.1 103.5L265.1 105.1"/> 
  </svg>
```

Размещаем сверху второй патч, который не имеет разрывов:

```html
<svg style="height:500;width:500" viewBox="0 0 500 500"> 
  <defs>
    
  </defs>
  <path fill="none" stroke="red"   stroke-width="20" stroke-dasharray="3.5 30" d="M55 68.1L57.1 85.6C59.2 103.1 63.5 138.1 81.4 161 99.4 183.9 131.1 194.5 147.9 181.5 164.8 168.5 166.9 131.8 184 115.1 201 98.5 233.1 101.8 249.1 103.5L265.1 105.1"/> 
   <path fill="none" stroke="red"   stroke-width="5"  d="M55 68.1L57.1 85.6C59.2 103.1 63.5 138.1 81.4 161 99.4 183.9 131.1 194.5 147.9 181.5 164.8 168.5 166.9 131.8 184 115.1 201 98.5 233.1 101.8 249.1 103.5L265.1 105.1"/>
```

Так получилось, потому что толщина линии размещается симметрично относительно осевой линии.

Пробовал обрезать третьим патчем нижние части столбиков, но не получается точно сместить командой `transform="translate"`

Если вас не устроит такой вид, симметричного расположения верт. черточек, то придется искать решение `JS`

Для прямых отрезков эту проблему можно решить с помощью подрезки третьим патчем.

```html
<svg style="height:500;width:500" viewBox="0 0 500 500"> 
 
  <path fill="none" stroke="red"  stroke-width="40" stroke-dasharray="3.5 30" d="M55 68.1 L390 68.1"/> 
    <path fill="none" stroke="red"  stroke-width="5" stroke-dasharray="3.5 30" d="M55 68.1 L390 68.1"/> 
     <path fill="none" stroke="red"   stroke-width="5"  d="M55 68.1 L390 68.1"/> 
      <path transform="translate(0 12)" fill="none" stroke="white"   stroke-width="20"  d="M55 68.1 L390 68.1"/>
   

</svg>
```